# Sitecore SXA CLI set up

Tags: sxa-cli

I am trying to set up `SXA CLI` on `Sitecore 10.3 and SXA 10.1.0`.

However, getting error as below.

Using Latest `node js - 21.6.2`

Has anyone configured SXA CLI on the latest Sitecore?

[image]

Logs below

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.2.4
2 info using node@v21.6.2
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 3ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 5ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 5ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 4ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 4ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\LENOVO\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load Completed in 20ms
16 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 20ms
17 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
20 verbose title npm i @sitecore/sxa-cli
21 verbose argv "i" "--global" "@sitecore/sxa-cli"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
23 timing npm:load:display Completed in 1ms
24 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-16T13_40_23_162Z-
25 verbose logfile C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-16T13_40_23_162Z-debug-0.log
26 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 12ms
27 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
28 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load Completed in 78ms
30 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 5 files
33 timing idealTree:init Completed in 9ms
34 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 4ms
35 silly idealTree buildDeps
36 silly fetch manifest @sitecore/sxa-cli@*
37 silly logfile done cleaning log files
38 http fetch GET 200 https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitecore/sxa-cli 1195ms (cache hit)
39 silly placeDep ROOT @sitecore/sxa-cli@ OK for:  want: *
40 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 1210ms
41 timing idealTree:node_modules/@sitecore/sxa-cli Completed in 0ms
42 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 1212ms
43 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
44 timing idealTree Completed in 1228ms
45 timing command:i Completed in 1244ms
46 verbose type invalid-json
47 verbose stack FetchError: invalid json response body at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitecore/sxa-cli reason: Unexpected token '<', "
47 verbose stack <!doctype "... is not valid JSON
47 verbose stack     at Response.json (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:79:13)
47 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:94:25)
47 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:118:23)
47 verbose stack     at async #nodeFromEdge (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1049:19)
47 verbose stack     at async #buildDepStep (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:917:11)
47 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:196:7)
47 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:159:5)
47 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:152:5)
47 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js:61:5)
48 verbose cwd C:\Users\LENOVO\source\repos
49 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
50 verbose node v21.6.2
51 verbose npm  v10.2.4
52 error code FETCH_ERROR
53 error errno FETCH_ERROR
54 error invalid json response body at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitecore/sxa-cli reason: Unexpected token '<', "
54 error <!doctype "... is not valid JSON
55 verbose exit 1
56 timing npm Completed in 1760ms
57 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1708090823668
58 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1708090823677
59 verbose code 1
60 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-16T13_40_23_162Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: can you add the logs from the local the folder and please mention NPM version
and make sure the version Node Js v21.6.2  NPM Should be a v10.2.4

Comment: @Ramesh, update the logs.. NPM version is v10.2.4

Comment: please try npm cache clean --force and npm install and  again install the package

Comment: Why are you using sxa 10.1.0 on XM 10.3? The versions should match.

Comment: Tried it Ramesh, no luck